# How can i create object for different endpoints in Single method, instead of if loop in java

Tags: java

```
if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Android")) {
    return new AndroidApi;
} else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("iOS")) {
    return new  IosAPi;
} else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Windows")) {
    return new WindowsApi;
}
```

How can i create object instead of if condition
There are 20 endpoints are there .

Comment: add some more detail.

Comment: Take a look at factory method pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put type and the supplier for API implementation in a map, like:

```
public static final Map<String, Supplier<Api>> supplierMap = Map.of(
        "android",  AndroidApi::new,
        "ios",      IosApi::new,
        "windows",  WindowsApi::new
);

public static Api getApi(String type) {
    return supplierMap.get(type.toLowerCase()).get();
}
```

assuming that all of them implement an interface.
You can call the above method this way:

```
Api api = getApi("Android");
```

Comment: Nice answer, Or this way `AndroidApi api = (AndroidApi) getApi("Android");`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use factory design pattern.

```
interface OperatingSystem
{
    void runProcess();
}

class AndroidApi implements OperatingSystem {
    public void runProcess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
class IosAPi implements OperatingSystem {
    public void runProcess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
class WindowsApi implements OperatingSystem {
    public void runProcess() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

class OSFactory
{
    static OperatingSystem getOPApi(String type){
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Android")) {
            return new AndroidApi();
        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("iOS")) {
            return new  IosAPi();
        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Windows")) {
            return new WindowsApi();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
public class Client{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OperatingSystem os=OSFactory.getOPApi("Android");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using factory design pattern or using Java Reflection API. 
Using Java Reflection API, we can do something like below,

Create a baseclass for all Api classes mentioned here. Consider the baseclass as `public abstract class BaseApi`.

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("Android","AndroidApi");
map.put("iOS","IosApi");
map.put("Windows","WindowsApi");

public static BaseApi getInstance(String type){

    BaseApi obj = (BaseApi)Class.forName(type).newInstance();
    return obj;
}
```